# How to chain methods inside the ruby group_by arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of slot time instances called `slots`, with a start time column.

I want to group these slots by `start_time.to_date` but i cant find the syntax to chain these methods together.

The error i am currently getting by running the below code is `undefined method to_date for :start_time:Symbol`

`slots.group_by(&:start_time.to_date)`

Comment: This can indeed be very misleading. You probably see `&:` followed by `start_time` but it's actually `&` followed by the _symbol_ `:start_time`. And because a symbol isn't a method in the first place, you can't chain anything here and instead get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the group_by block

```
slots.group_by {|slot| slot.start_time.to_date }
```